# Call inside of call loop

Tags: ruby

In a book that I'm attempting to follow there is a section that has left me completely stumped.  (The book is Practical Ruby Projects -> creating a turn based game)

```
class Choice
     def initialize(*rep, &action)
           @rep, @action = rep, action
     end

     def call(*args, &proc)
         @action.call(*args, &proc)
     end
end

choice = Choice.new("Move", x, y) {unit.move(x, y)}
```

So my question is about the `@action.call(...)`  It appears that `@action` is calling `call` from inside of `call`.  Wouldn't this create some sort of a infinite loop?

Also it appears to me that Choice.new doesn't have enough parameters.  initialize appears to need just 2, but Choice.new seems to be passing 3.  That being said I'm pretty fuzzy on this entire block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Parameters**

Constructor of `Choice` appears to accept any number of parameters because of [*splat* operator](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/) in front of `rep`. That said, the parameter list is `"Move", x, y` and `@rep`  in `initialize` became an array of those:

```
@rep = ["Move", x, y]
```

### **Codeblock**

The codeblock, passed to the constructor *is not a plain parameter*. It is denoted by leading ampersand (`&`) and does not count as parameter, it is a special case. So, the `@action` appears to be assigned to [*lambda*](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/):

```
@action = lambda { unit.move(x, y) }
```

### **Call**

The `call` method of `Choice` simply “redirects” the call to lambda, stored in `@action`. That said, any call to `Choice#call` will be calling lambda, stored in `@action` instance variable. In this particular case, `unit.move` will be called with parameters `@rep[1]` and `@rep[2]` (according to what `@rep` was initialized in constructor.)

Comment: Thanks for that.  The Parameters section makes alot more sense.  And I think i get the codeblock stored as a variable thing.  Follow up question though.  How does a variable call a method?  '@action' which is not of 'class Choice' invokes the method 'call'

Comment: `@action` invokes [`Proc#call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Proc.html#method-i-call) method on `Proc` object stored in `@action`. It has nothing to do with `Choice#call`, those are just homonyms. I guess you were confused by the same names assigned for different things.

Comment: To be more precise: what’s happenning there is actually like `(Proc.new { unit.move(x, y) }).call()`.

Comment: @DChaps, you are confusing yourself when you ask, "How does a variable call a method?".  Methods are not called, by a variable or any other object. You, the programmer, send methods to receivers. In the first instance you send `call` with arguments to `choice`. Ruby sees that `choice` is an instance of `Choice`, which tells it that it's that class' instance method `call` that you are sending.  When that method is executed, you send `call` with arguments to the receiver `@action`. As `@action` is an instance of the class `Proc`, Ruby identifies that method as `Proc#call`.